# My database gets an object returned instead of a value

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I am doing a post request on my database for user registers & every time the email gets returned as an object with this `{"email":"karl@gmail.com"}` instead of this `karl@gmail.com`

This is the nodejs

```
app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  const { email, name, password } = req.body;
  var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
  var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);
  knex
    .transaction((trx) => {
      trx
        .insert({
          hash: hash,
          email: email,
        })
        .into("login")
        .returning("email")
        .then((loginEmail) => {
          return trx("users")
            .returning("*")
            .insert({
              email: loginEmail[0],
              name: name,
              joined: new Date(),
            })
            .then((user) => {
              res.json(user[0]);
            });
        })
        .then(trx.commit)
        .catch(trx.rollback);
    })
    .catch((err) => res.status(400).json("E-mail is already in use"));
});
```

**This is how it looks in my 1st database**

```
 14 | Karl      | {"email":"karl@gmail.com"}         |       0 | 2022-01-18 04:02:03.643
```

This is how it looks in my 2nd database

```
 12 | $2a$10$WsbEExtpu14ps7aK6AYbxOknedUaLusApL8MlD8lv0lCtknBIuPE. | karl@gmail.com
```

Comment: Try `res.json(user[0].email)`

Comment: Still the word email is being added in an object with \ to the email itself

Comment: I don't see how this can return the object if it's just extracting one property.

Comment: Exactly my point, somehow the email variable of the second transaction isn't being treated as a column but as a value that gets inserted into the column

Comment: I thought the problem was with what was being returned by the controller, I didn't see that the problem is what's put in the DB.

Comment: Exactly, the second database should just duplicate whats inserted in the first one, but somehow it gets put in a totally different format

Comment: What are the 1st and 2nd database? Do you mean tables? Which table is which?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I meant tables. 1st table 'login' returns this ```12 | $2a$10$WsbEExtpu14ps7aK6AYbxOknedUaLusApL8MlD8lv0lCtknBIuPE. | karl@gmail.com ```  then second table 'users' returns this ```Karl      | {"email":"karl@gmail.com"}         |       0 | 2022-01-18 04:02:03.643```

Comment: You have them in the opposite order in the question, that was confusing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loginEmail` is an array of results, and each row is an object. You need to get the `email` property from that object.

```
            .insert({
              email: loginEmail[0].email,
              name: name,
              joined: new Date(),
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

you are receiving a JSON object decode that and you will get your email out. also don't understand why you store {"email": "karl@gmail.com"} when your column should be labeled email and store the value karl@gmail.com.
Best of luck!